# Windows Server 2016 - Can't RDP with one specific user

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, windows-server-2016

This is a new Windows 2016 server. We have three users on it and two of them are able to login without issue. The third one, no matter what we've tried (except rebooting; trying to avoid that) is not able to login. He keeps getting this error:

```
The task you are trying to do can't be completed because Remote Desktop Services is currently busy
```

I tried `rwinsta` to reset the session, resetting the user's password, running `shutdown /l` from a command prompt running under his credentials. Nothing worked. Any ideas?

[image: rdp error]

**UPDATE** Tried everything I knew to try. Nothing worked. Had to buckle down and reboot.

Comment: Is each user initiating the RDP from a different workstation? What is different about each workstation? What happens if problem user starts RDP from workstation of a working user? See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/952309/windows-10-remote-desktop-not-working-properly-the-remote-desktop-services-is-c)

Comment: Trying to RDP from the same two workstations. There are three of us, two workstations, and this particular user cannot login from either workstation while me and the other guy can both login from either workstation.

Comment: Possible licensing limitation? Can he login while you both are logged out?

Comment: Definitely not licensing. Even if we are all logged out, he gets the same error.

Comment: Happens on a Win10 Pro machine too - can't even log in through _local_ console anymore on that user. I'm _so_ glad Windows is now stable and Enterprise grade and you don't have to reboot anymore to fix problems.

Comment: for me , i just restarted the remote desktop services and its works fine after restarting the service. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What worked for me finally was to logon as a different admin user and start Task Manager, switch to the Users tab, right-click the problem user and select "Connect".

Answer (score 5):

Just had the same issue. Interesting that it was only me. Here's my fix. Since the message said RDP service is busy. But there were no sessions open. I went backdoor into the server via "Computer Management" and restarted the RDP service. Worked like a charm!!!

Comment: I tested this trick on a working VM before applying it on an affected production VM but the RDP service hanged while stopping. I had to connect using VNC and restart it.

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact problem. When I got in with the one account that could connect, I found in the Users tab of Task Manager that there were four sessions with null usernames. When I ended the Windows Login Application task for each, the null entries disappeared and I was able to log in via RDS normally. It did not require a restart.

Comment: Thank you, this step solved  my issue.